# in each worker node how many container can we have ! and how much executor can we have in one worker node

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

please i want to clarify this concept here is my questions :

1- is worker node concept is the same= 1 executor !!

2- how many in each worker node can we have container and how many executor can we have!!

3-in one executor how many core could we have ! i ask this question because when i created in gcp google cloud platform with dataproc service cluster i had 3 worker node with 2 core each i saw i have 6 executor and i was wondering if 1 executor can have only one core !!

Comment: One worker node can have multiple executors. Each executor can have multiple cores. You can set the number of executor cores using `spark.executor.cores`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider using `SparkContext.setSystemProperty("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true")`
which handles all of this configuration for you :)